# AndroidManifest file was deleted by accident

Tags: unity, android

I deleted the AndroidManifest file of my project which was located in Assets\Plugins\Android , so I tried creating new project and copying the Assets and everything but it seems that something is missing ,it's perfectly working in the editor , but as apk there are few things aren't working, I can't figure out why, and there isn't even a Plugins folder in my new project !

Comment: Let me just recommend using source control to prevent this being an issue in the future.

Comment: What few things aren't working? The better we understand the patient's symptoms, the better we can prescribe a suitable treatment.

Comment: @DMGregory you're right, I have a clock in my app, and it doesn't work ,there is a button too , while other buttons are working , the app is quite simple though

Comment: @Almo thanks for your help ,but I'm afraid that I didn't understand what source control is !

Comment: Google is your friend. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have some version of an apk that does work, it is possible to recover the AndroidManifest.xml from it.

Using [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) you can decompile the apk and get at some form of the original file. Note that it won’t have any comments that may have been in the original, and if you had any entries that explicitly remove automatically added elements using `<... tools:node="remove">` they would be no longer be present, but it should otherwise be identical.

The specifics of how to use apktool are documented on its website, but the general gist is

```
apktool d myapp.apk
```

Which will create a folder named myapp in the same place with all the files in it

Comment: Thanks ,i searched for such thing but couldn't find anything helpful , i'll try this